# Highlighting current date in Pivot Table (calendar)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

Surprisingly I cant figure it out how to make conditional format for a current date in Pivot Table calendar. I made a calendar and then formatted it to tables-pivot tables. In normal tables I know how it works (and it works as it should) with conditional formatting `> Highlight cell rules > Date occuring` or using

```
=B$2=today() in New Rules when defining using formula formatting...
```

In Pivot Table that is not "possible", and I dont know why. Other conditional formatting is alright but using any formula is not possible.

Any ideas how to adequatly mark current day on opening my workbook??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found it out how to do this.

Two ways of doing (depends which suits and fits better).

Somewhere in the Pivot table simply define current date with: (you can also hide it)

`=TEXT(TODAY();"TT")*1`  or

```
=A1=DAY(TODAY())
```

Then select the current date in certain month, and go to

> Conditional Formatting > Manage Rule > New Rule > Format only cells
>   that contain >> equal to >>> defined field (and set format as you
>   wish) > OK

There you have it.

[image]